# SQL query: HAVING, GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One with a list of shops and their ID's (shop_id)
and one with a list of employees with the ID (shop_id) of the shop they work at.

I have to print out each employee with a certain position form a certain shop.
My query is normally correct but I seem to get an error like tblEmployees.

Normally my query would look something like.

```
SELECT tblEmployees.Name, tblEmployees.Surname, tblShops.shop_id
FROM tblEmployees, tblShops
GROUP BY tblEmployees.shop_id
HAVING tblEmployees.shop_id = tblShops.shop_id;
```

Normally I get an error saying something like:

> tblEmployees.Name is not part of an aggregate function.

What I want to know is if it would solve my problem if I put every column that gives me this error under the GROUP BY statement. Or is there another way of fixing this error without it affecting the result I need to get from this query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses. You aren't aggregating here. You want to be joining your tables.

```
SELECT tblEmployees.Name, Surname, tblShops.shop_id
FROM tblEmployees JOIN tblShops
ON tblEmployees.shop_id=tblShops.shop_id
```

Comment: I guess this wasn't a very good example, but let's say I had to do this query and also SELECT only the shops with more  COUNT(tblEmployees.id)>5

Comment: Then you will want to group on _all_ of the other columns. `SELECT name, surname, tblEmployees.shopid from tblEmployees.shop_id=tblShops.shop_id GROUP BY name, surname, tblEmployees.shop_id HAVING COUNT(tblEmployees.id)>5;`